# Drupal: unwanted duplicated nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I'm experiencing some bugs with Drupal on a server. Sometimes when I update a node, a copy of this node (with the same title) is saved and I have to delete the wrong copies.

I suspect this is caused by the fUpload (multiple upload) CCK field, that allow you to upload multiple images. But I'm not sure about that, there is nothing in the logs about this.

Is this a common issue ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a common issue, and it's not an issue caused by Drupal core code.

Disable all the modules, or uninstall them, and then re-enable/install them one at time; each time you enable/install a new module, try creating a new node. Doing so, you should find which module causes the issue.
It is even better if you try with a fresh installation of Drupal.

Comment: what about FUpload module ? It requires 2 steps to store the images when you create a new node. I actually don't know what happened exactly, because my customer experienced the issue.

Comment: It could be that module to create the problem, or some other module that doesn't work well when FUpload is installed. Try disabling that module, and see what happens. The better way to verify which module is causing the problem is to try on a test site where you install the same modules installed in the site where the problem has been verified.

Comment: yeah I understand. The point is that it never occurred when I tested Drupal. It happened to my customer after a while. In other words, I'm not able to reproduce the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suspect a nodeapi create/update hook and/or some custom code around creating a second node. Just a guess.

Comment: what about FUpload module ? It requires 2 steps to store the images when you create a new node. I actually don't know what happened exactly, because my customer experienced the issue.

Comment: Did they click the Back button and hit Submit again?